# Unable to run jekyll theme in docker containers

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, jekyll

I am trying to run [Al-folio jekyll theme](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio) on my Windows 10 machine. When I run `docker-compose up` via powershell, I get the following error:

[image]

I am new to Jekyll and to docker. But I assume, I do not have to install anything if I am running a docker container like this.

How to resolve this issue?

The provided compose.yml file has the following content:

```
version: "3"
# this file uses prebuilt image in dockerhub
services:
  jekyll:
    image: amirpourmand/al-folio
    container_name: al-folio-website
    command: bash -c "
      rm -f Gemfile.lock
      && bundler exec jekyll serve --watch --port=8080 --host=0.0.0.0 --livereload --verbose --trace"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/jekyll
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still needs it, here's the issue thread on the official repo:
https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/issues/1540

As of today, it seems deleting the `posts/2021-07-04-diagrams.md` is the only known way to solve the issue on Windows.